# What is the reason to show 26 no line error? I am using kotlin 1.4.21 and android studio 4.1.1 .Please give me a solution

Tags: android, kotlin

[just focus on 26 no variable that is assigned on webView function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Octl1.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Octl1.png)

Comment: Please, don't paste your code as image, is hard to see and help you. Please take the time to absorb SO's recommendations addressed to new users (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You may take the tour (https://stackoverflow.com/tour); then do read what's on-topic here (https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to declare the sportweb variable globally, that means outside the function "webview()"

Comment: your welcome, if it helped please accept my answer :)